# How do i Handle a "ñ" character that comes as a "@PathVariable" in a request, Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, url, urlencode

I have a RESTController that has the following method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/equipos/ciudad/{ciudad}", produces = {"application/json"})
public ResponseEntity<List<EquipoBean>> getEquiposByCiudad(@PathVariable(name = "ciudad") String ciudad) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(service.getEquiposByCiudad(ciudad), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

It works when i send normal characters even if there are multiple words with spaces between them, but when i send it the "ñ" character i get an Exception like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:475) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:260) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I tried googling around to search for the answer but i didn't get to the solution so i'm asking here, is there a way for me to set my RESTController to properly handle those types of special characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your client is [expected](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.4) to [URL-encode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) such character. So `ñ` becomes `%C3%B1`.

---

You seem to be using a Spanish city name as parameter. So I will use `A Coruña` as example. If your client is written in Java, you can use [`URLEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

```java
String url = "http://example.org?q=" + URLEncoder.encode("A Coruña", "UTF-8");
```

Starting with Java 10, you can use:

```java
String url = "http://example.org?q=" + 
    URLEncoder.encode("A Coruña", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

With that, `A Coruña` will be encoded to `A+Coru%C3%B1a`.

Comment: Everything you have said is exactly right.  But do we know that the HTTP request is being made from code and not from a browser?

Comment: @VGR Well, the OP didn't provide any details on what the client is like. With that example in Java, I just intended to provide the OP with a starting point. Hopefully it's helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that as the exception says `ñ` cannot be present in a valid URL. The RFC defines a very specific set of characters that can be allowed and ALL other characters need to be URL-encoded.

So the solution should be that whoever is calling your API needs to url-encode their request and your service will work just fine.